# Creating an array from JSON data

Tags: html, arrays, json, angular

I'm trying to create an array from this localStorage data. This because I want to bind the data to a list in my HTML doc. Since `<li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user.name}}</li>` only supports arrays I need to convert my JSON to an array.

LocalStorage JSON:

```
Key: User Value: {"name":"Kevin","country":"Canada","about":"Test","image":""}
```

Comment: Why don't you store it as array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable named users

```
users:any = [];
```

then

```
let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
this.users.push(user);
```

Comment: I get this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null`

Comment: try this <li *ngFor="let user of users">{{user?.name}}</li>

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using map function:

`var users = Object.keys(obj).map(function(x) { return obj[x] });`